# How to use tensor shape parameters for something useful?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use the shape of an incoming tensor to form the output, sort of like this:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def myFunc(x):
   sz = tf.shape(x)[1]
   # .. other stuff
   z = K.repeat_elements(y, sz, axis=1)
```

This results in `TypeError: Tensor object cannot be interpreted as integer`.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know are that the dimension of `x` is known in advance, you can use `x.shape[1]` instead of `tf.shape(x)[1]`, which will return an integer.

But I would advise to use [`tf.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat) instead of  `tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements`. `tf.repeat` will work regardless the usage of `tf.shape(x)` or `x.shape`.